# mysql update query, merging two values

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a table like this

```
USER   |   DATA
----------------
User1  |   123
User1  |   456
User2  |   456
User3  |   123
User4  |   789
```

and i have a UNIQUE constraint for User-Data. Now i want to replace all "456" with "123", so in the end i'd have

```
USER   |   DATA
----------------
User1  |   123
User2  |   123
User3  |   123
User4  |   789
```

I really thought that it would be easy, u_U any idea how to proceed? any help would be appreciated =)

Thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE IGNORE yourtable SET `data`=123 WHERE `data`=456
```

Not so hard was it.

But how do you want to deal with this scenario:

```
USER   |  DATA
--------------
userx  |  123
userx  |  456
```

?

Comment: `UPDATE IGNORE` i knew it had to be something this simple.. i guess that after the update i'll have to delete all rows containing `456` and then I'll just go on my merry way Thxs

Answer (score 2):

*"With the IGNORE keyword, the update statement does not abort even if errors occur during the update. Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts occur are not updated"*

So,
Update any rows that would not violate the unique constraint.
If any rows would, just delete them

```
UPDATE IGNORE Table SET data=123 WHERE data=456 
DELETE FROM Table WHERE data=456
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique constraint, you can't have two entries with User1 - 123. So your last result is correct. You also can't have two entries with User2 - 456. Cause you have a unique constraint combined with both fields.